Check if SMTP server is online
How to check if SMTP is online and running?
func (p *sys_ping) smtp(host string) string {
    client, err := smtp.Dial(host)
    if err != nil {
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(p.delay) * time.Second)
        return ""
    }
// check if response code is 220 or something similar to check if server is running
    client.Quit()
    return host
}

The above code is connecting to the SMTP. It works. But how can you check if the response code is 220? I guess the correct code should be 220 to check if the server is running correctly?

Dial is simply opening a connection.  If you want a response code, you will have to send an SMTP request; e.g. a HELO, ELOH, etcetera.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321#section-3.1

@StephenC, that's not quite correct for SMTP: in that protocol, the server is required to respond first with its status message (this is employed by some servers to combat spammers: the server defers sending its status message for a little time, and if the client attempts to send something first, it's deemed to be non-complying and is deined access).

I’m voting to close this question because it indicates insufficient research on behalf of the asker (there's no sense to ask how an openly-documented protocol works).

@kostix I'm asking this specific question because I'm in doubt if it is the correct (most efficient) way to do it. I might read the docs wrong. And thats exactly why I ask the experts on stackoverflow.

As @kostix rightfully remarks smtp.Dial calls smtp.NewClient, which calls _, _, err := text.ReadResponse(220) (GitHub):
// Dial returns a new [Client] connected to an SMTP server at addr.
// The addr must include a port, as in "mail.example.com:smtp".
func Dial(addr string) (*Client, error) {
    // ...
    return NewClient(conn, host)
}

// NewClient returns a new [Client] using an existing connection and host as a
// server name to be used when authenticating.
func NewClient(conn net.Conn, host string) (*Client, error) {
    text := textproto.NewConn(conn)
    _, _, err := text.ReadResponse(220)
    if err != nil {
        text.Close()
        return nil, err
    }
    // ...
}

So, after smtp.Dial you either have a working SMTP connection (with a 220 response) or get an error back.

yep , server should respond with code 220 in order to accept connections
 import (
        "net/smtp"
        "time"
        "strings"
    )
    
    func (p *sys_ping) smtp(host string) string {
        client, err := smtp.Dial(host)
        if err != nil {
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(p.delay) * time.Second)
            return ""
        }
        defer client.Quit()
    
        // Read initial resp code from server
        response, err := client.Text.ReadResponse(220)
        if err != nil || !strings.HasPrefix(response, "220") {
            return ""
        }
    
        return host
    }


client.Text.ReadResponse() returns 3 variables. But this is still not working code, response, err := client.Text.ReadResponse(220); fmt.Println(code, response) The fmt.Println is never executed

@krisso, please read the net/smtp's source code (it's no more complicated than your example, really ;-)) — you'll learn smtp.Dial calls smtp.NewClient which establishes an SMTP session and then calls Text.ReadResponse(220), erroring out if the operation fails or the status reported is not 220. Therefore, the answer is invalid (and your problem is solved).
